# Why does git not have a 'git ignore' command?

Tags: git, gitignore

I understand how to setup git to use the .gitignore file to ignore files but was wondering why this has not been a command feature that makes this task slightly less tedious. I will post this question to the git-scm mailing list later but was wondering if anyone here might have a valid reason for the lack of a ...

```
'git ignore <pattern>'
```

... feature. I am sure there are other developers that would find this feature useful.

Comment: There is such a thing, in the form of a `.gitignore`

Comment: Why do you want a command? Just `cat > .gitignore`

Answer (score 5):

Probably because it's just as quick to open `.gitignore` in a text editor or do `$ echo <pattern> >> .gitignore`.

Comment: Of course, the `echo` command could easily be put into a bash script called `git-ignore`. I'm not sure what else would be required to turn this into a `git ignore` command. Does it need to be placed in a particular directory?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, it just has to be somewhere on you `PATH`

Comment: I agree... it isn't that difficult to actually add entries to the .gitignore file whether it be via a bash script or alias. Its just less intuitive to the newbie git user.

Comment: Also, one might enjoy built in logic that would correct files that were accidentally committed that initially should have been ignored.  This would save time.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice actually there are numerous ways to ignore files: `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` is a private one (untracked) per repository, `.gitignore` in the repo itself (and a custom `.gitignore` in each directory of the repo's tree) (tracked), and `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` for all repos of the user (untracked). And I think there's also a system-wide one, not sure. A `git ignore` command can thus be as complicated as remembering all those different locations. Just a thought.

Comment: @PerlDog All good points. I imagine that `git ignore` could be made more complex than the simple `echo` command suggested here.

Comment: It's equally easy to make a list of files for staging, yet we have a `git add <pattern>` command.